# Visual studio no of users support

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My company has purchased license for

visual studio proffessional 2015 sngl olp 1 license no level.

Can it be used in any no of machines within organization ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Visual Studio 2015 Whitepaper found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350), it can be installed on as many devices as you wish.

> Where the Software can be Installed and Run
>
> The licensed user can install and use the software on any number of devices. The software can be installed and used on
>   your devices at work, at home, at school, and even on devices at a customer’s office or on dedicated hardware hosted by a
>   3
>   rd party. Most subscriber software can also be run in Microsoft Azure VMs. However, the software is otherwise not
>   licensed for use in production environments

This seems to indicate that the software is licensed per user, regardless of the number of devices he/she uses it on. So as long as it is just one developer, it should be fine to install it on multiple computers.

Comment: One user here refers to one organization ?

Comment: No,  one license is per **user**. That is a single person.

Comment: You can switch that person once every 6 months.